# Broken motherboard, bios failure

Tags: windows-8.1, motherboard, hardware-failure, chipset

After some tests I have found that the BIOS is broken.

I have tried to make sure it is the BIOS that's broken. And after unplugging everything unnecessary the same result remains.

And now I would like to replace the broken motherboard with a new one without a direct reinstallation of the operative system. Is this possible?

On the hard drive windows 8.1 is installed and on the motherboard a AMD chip is found.

Is the installation on the hard drive possible to use again? Can the motherboard be upgraded without a reinstallation beeing necessarily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to reinstall Windows 8 when upgrading my motherboard, cpu and memory, but not my HDD?](http://superuser.com/questions/523737/do-i-have-to-reinstall-windows-8-when-upgrading-my-motherboard-cpu-and-memory), [Which steps are needed to change motherboard on Windows 7 without reinstalling?](http://superuser.com/questions/125323/which-steps-are-needed-to-change-motherboard-on-windows-7-without-reinstalling)

Comment: [How to replace properly motherboard and cpu on a windows (7) machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/642246/how-to-replace-properly-motherboard-and-cpu-on-a-windows-7-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now I have transferred HDDs with installed Windows 8.1 between different hardware platforms many time and without a single problem. Especially it is very smooth when you are exchanging the platform for the same one (Intel for Intel, AMD for AMD), but actually I have not experienced any issues until now whatsoever.

It was the era of Windows XP where changing the platform was a matter of luck, but with Windows 8.1 (even with Windows 7) I didn't have any issues... and I'm running my own computer service, meaning that things like this happens daily

Until now, I didn't have any issue with Windows 10 as well

And I am very grateful to Microsoft for this, as this saved my life (time and money)

Comment: Then I will do so and change the motherboard. Thanks for your trustworthy answer :)

Answer (score -1):

No.  Windows is really picky about drivers and hardware changes like that and, even if you manage to make it boot with a new motherboard, you'll likely have stability problems.  Save yourself the headaches.  Get your data off the hard drive and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I see. The thing is just that I had some projects going on when the BIOS failed that I would like to get finished with before I do a propper reinstallation. ^^ Do you think an upgrade to WIN 10 would do? (If I get it working in the unstable mode)

Comment: Upgrading may help but it may also make things worse.  Go ahead and try it but make sure you have good backups of your data.

Comment: Not sure how you can so categorically say NO? How many times you have tried to do that? It is not correct to give such an advice if it is based on a single experience or if you were not lucky for some reason when you have tried. With Windows 8.1 this is absolutely wrong and Windows 8/8.1/10 is very flexible when it comes to drivers and it can handle hardware change very well